# MSB4036 The "FormatLocalizedString" task was not found

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, .net-core

```
Error   MSB4036 The "FormatLocalizedString" task was not found. Check the following: 1.) The name of the task in the project file is the same as the name of the task class. 2.) The task class is "public" and implements the Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask interface. 3.) The task is correctly declared with <UsingTask> in the project file, or in the *.tasks files located in the "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\MSBuild\Current\Bin\amd64" directory. REST.Core.Host  C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v17.0\TypeScript\Microsoft.TypeScript.targets 69
```

I am getting this build error while building my rest core solution.[image]

Comment: Can you add some context? How long have you had the problem? Following what manipulations?

Comment: I am building this REST.core solution for first time in my laptop

Comment: Sound like a VS extension missing. If you know a machine where is work, you can compare the VS installation.

Comment: I am getting this issue even with blank Rest core api project also. I believe I am missing something here.

Comment: I have compared Individual components installed in my machine and other machines appears to be same

Comment: What is "Rest core api project"?

Comment: Did you also check extension?

Comment: I tried to create new ASP.net core web api project and when I build that project getting same error. About extension , I believe you meant manage extensions. I couldn't find anything specific there.

Comment: Do you try to create a new project in a new solution? Can you show the csproj?

Comment: yes i created new project in new solution.

<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="6.2.3" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>

Comment: Sound normal... Can you try the command `dotnet build`?